# 'Range of Object' _Worksheet Failed - Userform

Tags: excel, vba, range, userform

I'm working in VBA - Excel 2016

I'm trying to take input from a userform called from one sheet, find the next blank row on another sheet and insert the value. However I keep getting a runtime error - 'Range of Object' _Worksheet Failed. The form is called from within another form.

I've tried various solutions but nothing seems to work.

I am using almost the same code elsewhere which works when the form is called and the value is inserted on the same sheet, so have concluded that it must be down to accessing the other sheet.

It fails on this line:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Suppliers").Range("A" & NextRow) = SupplierName
```

The code I am using is below.

```
Private Sub addSupplierConfirm_Click()

'Initialise variables
Dim SupplierName As String

'Assign variables
SupplierName = addSupplierName.Value

If (SupplierName = "") Then
    MsgBox ("Please enter a supplier name")
    Exit Sub
End If

'Find next row on supplier sheet add supplier name

NextRow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Suppliers").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Suppliers").Range("A" & NextRow) = SupplierName

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Sort Suppliers
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Suppliers").ListObjects("tbl_suppliers").Sort.SortFields. _
    Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Suppliers").ListObjects("tbl_suppliers").Sort.SortFields. _
    Add Key:=Range("tbl_suppliers[[#All],[Suppliers]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
    Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Suppliers").ListObjects("tbl_suppliers").Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

'Activate home page
Sheets("Expenses").Activate
Range("A1").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'Unload form
addSupplierName.Value = ""
UfAddSupplier.Hide

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.

I have checked that `NextRow` is positive and that `Suppliers` exists along with leading/trailing spaces.

I now have this runtime error "Method 'Value2' of Object 'Range' failed". 

The value is being added to the bottom of the table but is not being sorted as I guess the runtime error is preventing the rest of the code from executing.

Comment: I added the `Value2` from your comment previously where you suggested using `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Suppliers").Range("A" & NextRow).Value2 = SupplierName`. The code is failing on that line.

Comment: `addSupplierName.Value` is returning the same value as supplied in the input. Looks like I might need to find another solution, thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Sure thing, I'll send it over now. Thanks!

Comment: Simple error: you cannot access the worksheet while the form is still open. Try it yourself. If a form is showing you cannot select / change a sheet or cell. So, you need to hide the form earlier in your code. Move `UfAddSupplier.Hide` a bit up (before you access the sheet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access the sheet while a form is still showing. Move `UfAddSupplier.Hide` a bit further up in your `sub` just before accessing the sheet and everything should work as intended:

```
Private Sub addSupplierConfirm_Click()

'Initialise variables
Dim SupplierName As String

'Assign variables
SupplierName = addSupplierName.Value

If (SupplierName = "") Then
    MsgBox ("Please enter a supplier name")
    Exit Sub
End If

UfAddSupplier.Hide

'Find next row on supplier sheet add supplier name

NextRow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Suppliers").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Suppliers").Range("A" & NextRow) = SupplierName
...
...
...
```

Comment: Still getting the same error. If I run the userform on it's own (not called from the initial userform) it works fine, without having to hide the form before accessing the sheet. Could it be an issue with the initial userform being active?

Comment: Of course. **No** `UserForm` (unless the form is shown modeless) can be shown while you access a sheet.

Comment: Finally got it to work! Your solution was correct, just had to hide the original userform first before loading the new one, rather than loading it on top. Thanks for all of your help!